# Rename Multiple sheets in Excel with cell value from same sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a VBA project. I have a workbook with multiple tabs from different workbooks. The names of all the tabs are the same, however since they come from different files, I would like to name them based on the filenames they are extracted from. The filenames are present in the cell EC1 of every tab. I would like to name all the sheets in the workbook based on the value present in cell EC1 of each individual sheet.

I have the following code:

```vb
Sub RenameSheet()
    Dim rs As Worksheet
    For Each rs In Sheets
    rs.Name = rs.Range("EC1")
    Next rs
End Sub
```

I have been getting a 1004 error from the above code.

I tried this code too:

```vb
Sub RenameSheet()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xRngAddress As String
    Dim xName As String
    Dim xSSh As Worksheet
    Dim xInt As Integer
    xRngAddress = Application.ActiveCell.Address
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        xName = xWs.Range(xRngAddress).Value
        If xName <> "" Then
            xInt = 0
            Set xSSh = Nothing
            Set xSSh = Worksheets(xName)
            While Not (xSSh Is Nothing)
                Set xSSh = Nothing
                Set xSSh = Worksheets(xName & "(" & xInt & ")")
                xInt = xInt + 1
            Wend
            If xInt = 0 Then
                xWs.Name = xName
            Else
                If xWs.Name <> xName Then
                    xWs.Name = xName & "(" & xInt & ")"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Some sheets do get renamed, however some do not. I have checked for duplicate sheet names, and there are none. I have also checked if the filename is in the correct range (cell), and it is present.

Comment: Most likely the value in cell EC1 is not a valid sheet name (too long, or invalid characters).

Comment: If @BigBen is rigth you could check if the cell contains one of these characters \ , / , * , ? , : , [ , ] and if its length exeeds 31

Answer (score 0):

There might be problems with the value if it contains some special characters. The excel sheets can have some [restrictions](http://www.excelcodex.com/2012/06/worksheets-naming-conventions/) for their names, if thats the problem, my code could be the solution.
It cuts the string to a maximum length of 31 chars and deletes all the special chars which are not allowed in names.

```
Sub RenameSheet()

Dim rs As Worksheet

For Each rs In Sheets
sheetName = without_special_chars(rs.Range("EC1").Value)
If Len(sheetName) > 31 Then
    sheetName = Left(sheetName, 31)
End If
rs.Name = sheetName
Next rs

End Sub

Function without_special_chars(text As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
Const special_chars As String = "-.,:;#+ß'*?=)(/&%$§!~\}][{"
For i = 1 To Len(special_chars)
text = Replace(text, Mid(special_chars, i, 1), "")
Next i
without_special_chars = text
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Rename Multiple Worksheets

**A Quick Fix**

- Your first code should have been something like this:

  ```
  Sub renameWorksheetsQF()
      Dim ws As Worksheet
      For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
          ws.Name = ws.Range("EC1").Value
      Next ws
  End Sub
  ```

  Note the not so subtile differences.

**In Depth**

```
Option Explicit

Sub renameWorksheets()

    On Error GoTo clearError
    Const cAddress As String = "A1" ' "EC1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim oName As String
    Dim nName As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        oName = ws.Name
        Set cel = ws.Range(cAddress)
        If IsError(cel) Then
            Debug.Print "Cell '" & cAddress & "' in worksheet '" _
                & oName & "' contains the error value '" & cel.Text & "'."
        Else
            If IsEmpty(cel) Then
                Debug.Print "Cell '" & cAddress & "' in worksheet '" _
                    & oName & "' is an empty cell."
            Else
                nName = CStr(cel.Value)
                On Error GoTo RenameError
                If oName <> nName Then
                    ws.Name = nName
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Worksheet '" & oName _
                        & "' had previously been renamed."
                End If
                On Error GoTo clearError
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

RenameError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Debug.Print "     Could not rename '" & oName & "' to '" & nName & "'."
    Resume Next
clearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Debug.Print "     Unexpected error."
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```